# getting user defined object instances from resultset

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I have a coding assignment in which I got stuck...

I have an Account table in which I need to select  the unprocessed accounts; that's what I have done easy

now the assignment ask me to return each account in an Accounts array; which I got from query

*So, how I could return an account array(how I could fill in the each unporcessed Account in resultset) into Accounts array to return from that already defined function which I am not allowed to chnge.*

**Is it any way that the resultset: return a single row it contain as an account instance?**

we need to use Java 5 and not allowed to implement third party library

P.S

I have already tried:

```
Account account = (Account) rs.getObject("ID");` this has a classcast exception
```

and

`Account account = (Account) rs.getObject("ID",Account.Class);` this has also some other exception

I have also read about: ***Customized Type Mappings*** but I am not sure that even after doing all what it sugggest I would get the desired resuts

and this solution also involves  creating customtype(in this case account) on databaselevel first which I am also not allowed to touch

as mentioned in some other answer

please share your exp.

Answer (score 0):

The Class cast exception you are getting is expected because rs.getObject("ID") does not give an object that is of the class Account. You can create an array (or a List) of Account objects and populate it while iterating through the result set. (Assuming that you have all information of an account in a single row of the result set). Let us also assume the Account class as follows :

```
class Account {
    int id;
    String accountType;
    String accountHolderName;
    long accountBalance;
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

//Assuming the table columns that you are querying have these fields for each row:

```
AccountId | AccountType | AccountHolderName | AccountBalance | ...
101       | Checking    | John              | 100            | ...
```

//Populating the Account Objects

```
    Account [] accArray = new accArray [sizeOfResultSet];
    int i=0;
    while (rs.next()){
            Account current = new Account();
            current.id  = rs.getInt("AccountId");
            current.accountType = rs.getString("AccountType");
            current.accountHolderName = rs.getString("AccountHolderName");
            ...
            ...
            ...
    }
```